# Simulink Parallel Sensitivity Analysis Fails

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to perform a parallel sensitivity analysis on my Cluster. I am using the defaul example:

```
edit sdoVOR_cmddemo_sa
```

To perform the parallel sensitivity analysis I added the following lines and modifications to the script:

```
opt1 = sdo.EvaluateOptions;
opt1.UseParallel = true;
[dirs,files] = sdo.getModelDependencies('sdoVOR');
opt1.ParallelFileDependencies = files;
opt1.EvaluatedModel = 'sdoVOR';
y = sdo.evaluate(evalDesign,p,pSmpl,opt1);
```

Everything works fine if I use only my multicore machine. But when I run the script on a cluster I receive the following errors:

```
Analyzing and transferring files to the workers ...done.
Error using parallelsim.setupWorkers (line 104)
An error occurred interpreting function call.
Error in sdo.internal.configureSensitivityEvaluation>localInitParallel (line 95)
parallelsim.setupWorkers(mdl, dependdir, options.ParallelFileDependencies)
Error in sdo.internal.configureSensitivityEvaluation (line 51)
    localInitParallel(opts,cleanup_obj);
Error in sdo.evaluate>localCreateCleanupFcn (line 199)
cleanup_obj = sdo.internal.configureSensitivityEvaluation(...
Error in sdo.evaluate (line 110)
fcnCleanup = localCreateCleanupFcn(opts);
Error in Test (line 260)
[pOpt,opt_info] = sdo.evaluate(evalDesign,p,pSmpl,opt1);
```

Please, check if you can reproduce this error when you run the script in parallel ON A CLUSTER (not a single multicore machine) and try to figure out a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solve it!
The problem was that I did not installed Simulink on the node cluster.